# Build libgit2sharp for .net 2.0

Tags: libgit2sharp

Did anyone succeed in building libgit2sharp using .NET 2.0?
I need to make the library work under VS 2005 and have many 3.5 features to re-write.
Does anyone know of a better way to work under VS 2005 with the library or is there .net 2.0 library version available anywhere?

Answer (score 2):

> Is there .net 2.0 library version available anywhere?

There is no official LibGit2Sharp version working against .Net 2.0. Only .Net 3.5 or Mono 2.10 are currently supported.

> Does anyone know of a better way to work under VS 2005?

Current version **[embeds a lightweight compatibility layer](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/tree/vNext/LibGit2Sharp/Core/Compat)** to ease a future migration towards .Net 4.0.

Provided you're committed to make it to work against .Net 2.0, I'd suggest you to adapt a similar kind a isolation layer, and (*as much as possible, trying to*) avoid altering the code of the library. This will ease the backporting of any future LibGit2Sharp update in your project.